# Is hello_ll.c in libfuse obsolete?

Tags: c, linux, fuse

I learning how to use libfuse with hello_ll.c in `example` directory.
[hello_ll.c](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/example_2hello__ll_8c.html)

But it looks like using different API  that does not match current version libfuse.

For instance, `fuse_session_new` takes 4 args in this example, But same one that defines in my `/usr/include/fuse/fuse_lowlevel.h` only takes two args.

```
struct fuse_session *fuse_session_new(struct fuse_session_ops *op, void *data);
```

Is it obsolete?

Comment: There is `#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 34` on top `it looks like using different API` Could you be more specific? Which line exactly looks like different to what API?

Comment: I added one example that fuse_session_new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at an example for [FUSE for linux](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/include/fuse_lowlevel.h#L1932) and looking at a header for [FUSE on MacOS](https://github.com/osxfuse/fuse/blob/8071bd97494cd2982ed5635525b8a754edfbfb0f/include/fuse_lowlevel.h#L1674) or looking at a header from a really *really* old fuse version, as

- `fuse_session_new(struct fuse_session_ops *op, void *data)` [was in 2005 renamed to](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/commit/a148242fb80fa2127fdaf41de63e2d81dc8006ef) `struct fuse_session *fuse_lowlevel_new(const char *opts, const struct fuse_lowlevel_ops *op, size_t op_size, void *userdata);`
- which [was in 2016 renamed to](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/commit/f164e9b8ca319dd1279384ff495b5fa91e778d9e) `struct fuse_session *fuse_session_new(struct fuse_args *args, const struct fuse_lowlevel_ops *op,   size_t op_size, void *userdata);`.

> Is hello_ll.c in libfuse obsolete?

No, it is not.